# PostgreSQL COPY: Skip First Two Lines off CSV

Tags: mysql, postgresql, csv, import

Every week I receive a number of CSV files to import into my PostgreSQL database for analysis. The problem is that a number of these files come with a security disclaimer line above the header line, like this:

```
This document contains Personal Identifying Information (PII) and is For Official Use Only (FOUO). It shall not be disclosed outside any...
"Last Name",Suffix,"First Name","Middle Name",DOB,"Work Email","Home Email","Employment Status",UPN,"Ship To Address","Ship To City"...
```

Is there a way to have the COPY statement skip over the first two lines while bringing the rest of the file into the table? MySQL has the `IGNORE 2 LINES` clause for the `LOAD DATA LOCAL` command; is there anything similar for PostgreSQL?

Comment: Look at the `program` option of the `copy` command. For Linux it could be `program 'tail -n+3 myfile.csv'`.

Comment: @Abelisto, that IS a fantastic idea, except that the work computer that the prod database is on is a Windows box.

Comment: Yet another "fantastic" :) idea: load file into the temp table like `create temp table t (x text)` as a flat text, then save it to the file except first two rows. In any case it is impossible to skip n lines using pure `copy` command.

Comment: @Abelisto, you are on to something here! Loving it! You have sparked a couple of ideas for me, and I will report back what I come up with.